# doxygen complains about my image-in-link tag

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I have a README.md file which gets processed by doxygen, which has the following line:

```
Branch Build Status: Master [![Master Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) | Development: [![Development Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers.svg?branch=development)](https://travis-ci.org/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers)
```

Doxygen 1.8.13 tells me:

```
README.md:3: warning: Unexpected html tag <img> found within <a href=...> context
```

repeated four times. Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen version 1.8.13 is from December 29, 2016 and a little bit older, the current version is 1.8.18

With version 1.8.13 I get also the message as indicated, with version 1.8.18 this message is gone and the images are shown (actually the message is gone since version 1.8.15).